# Can I add an encoding header to a ContentResult?

Tags: c#, html, .net-core, character-encoding, asp.net-core-webapi

For testing purpose I have implemented an endpoint on our ASP.NET Core Web Api, that returns the HTML content of a RSS news feed article.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/api/[controller]/NewsItemHtml/{id}")]
public IActionResult GetNewsItemHtml(int id)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id.ToString())) return new StatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    using (NewsBLL bll = new NewsBLL(_dbContext))
    {
        NewsItem newsItem = bll.GetNewsItem(id);
        if (newsItem == null) return new StatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

        return new ContentResult
        {
            ContentType = "text/html",
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = newsItem.Description
        };
    }
}
```

Though I am getting the HTML from the endpoint, the encoding is wrong as shown in below screenshot (the language is danish) - Sorry for the large image size.
[image]

How can I add a header with the right encoding, before returning the ContentResult? Or can I go with a better suited return type? Since we are using ASP.NET Core Web Api, I can not use the HttpResponseMessage return type, from what I understand?

I hope someone can help me solve this. Thanks for your time so far.

EDIT: for some reason the encoding looks right, when I am hitting the endpoint from Postman. But not in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

return it like:

```
return Content("<html><body><div><h3>sometext</h3></div></body></html>", "text/html", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: This helped me resolve an issue with arabic characters in an API response. Thanks. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this with ContentResult in Asp.Net Core is to include charset in ContentType so that it will be sent with [Content-Type-header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type):

```
return new ContentResult
{
    ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8",
    StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
    Content = newsItem.Description
};
```